# What are our best, general-audience questions?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I've learned that we can [submit questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125405/1438) to be published on the StackExchange Google Plus and Facebook feeds. One of my [suggestions](https://plus.google.com/101120115153580954446/posts/8V2HSc4NcAK) was recently used.  As of today, that question now sits at the top of our [Greatest Hits](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) thanks to some positive, anonymous feedback to Bruce Alderman's [answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/629/68).  So it would seem that using the [Google form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEM0RjNXT3hpZUNpRFZaU2ZqSGpQb0E6MQ) to submit good content helps us get readership.  And perhaps more exposure will help us find more participants and reduce the odds we will be shut down.

So, which questions should we suggest to promote on the network's G+ and Facebook accounts?

---

So that we don't flood the editors, please record any questions you submit as answers to this post.  Also, I'd like to keep a running, ranked list of which questions are our best advertisements for the future.  Finally, what factors influenced your decision?  (Otherwise you might, like me, make a trivial answer that is converted to a comment. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

### [Does 1st Kings say that pi = 3?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/567/68)

Math questions are popular to a technical audience.  Plus pi is mysterious and intriguing.  Finally, possible Biblical contradictions are of interest to both religious and non-religious folks.

Answer (score 4):

[Does baptizing come after discipling in Matthew 28:19?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1565/does-baptizing-come-after-discipling-in-matt-28)

I like this one because it is generally used as the foundation of any missiological activity undertaken by a congregation. It is also frequently misused and misunderstood within that context.

Comment: Just to make sure: did you submit it to the [Google form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEM0RjNXT3hpZUNpRFZaU2ZqSGpQb0E6MQ)?  Also, I cleaned up the question a touch to get it ready for "prime time".  You might want to double-check your answer.  (I made one minor edit.)

Answer (score 4):

### [Does the Bible mention unicorns?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/106/68)

I think this question will interest the general Stack Exchange reader because:

a. [Unicorns!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/1438)

and

b. It's an odd translation problem with an interesting solution.

In addition, this question and its answers really show off a strength of the Biblical Hermeneutics community: clearing away cruft and confusion that clings to the texts without removing the mystery and wonder.

---

For purposes of benchmarking, the question currently has 303 views and is fourth from the bottom of the first page of [Greatest Hits](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits).

---

Was [posted](https://plus.google.com/101120115153580954446/posts/E4PJtxKqSRc) on June 1.  As of today, the question has 521 views and is 6<sup>th</sup> on our greatest hits.  [Not all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133213/global-notification-of-moderator-elections-have-the-wrong-url#comment369464_133213) of the traffic came from Facebook and G+, however.

Answer (score 1):

**[The Eye of the Needle](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/223/the-eye-of-the-needle)**

I think this is a good candidate because it is based on a popular misconception.

Answer (score 0):

### [Who are the morning stars in Job 38:7?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/706/68)

I've always liked this question (and the answer).  I submitted it in particular because of the [transit of Venus](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/331/68).

---

For bench-marking, the question currently has 177 views and heads the [third page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits?page=3) of our greatest hits.