# Let's ask about Astronomy

Tags: discussion, challenge

This summer the planet Venus will [pass between the sun and the earth](http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/OH/transit12.html) (a twice in a lifetime event).  Meanwhile, the Bible, as an Ancient Near East text, is filled with astronomical references.  So for our next challenge, I propose asking (and answering) questions on astronomy in the Bible.

Assuming this is a reasonable idea, I'd like to:

1. Put the challenge on our [Community Bulletin](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/330/68).
2. Contact <strike>[Astronomy.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51/astronomy)</strike> [Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/) to see [if any of their users would like to partner with us](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1315/9426).
3. Ask as many astronomy questions as we can think of between now and the end of May.
4. Submit a question to be [published](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/68) (if accepted) on the network's G+ and Facebook accounts.  (Please use the answers to this question to suggest the best question.  We'll submit the one that has the most votes.)
5. Learn a lot about astronomy in the Bible and observe the transit on June 5.